# Excel Pivot Table Remnants - VBA Solution?

Tags: excel, formatting, pivot-table

When a pivot table is updated and the number of rows/columns is reduced (the table is contracted), how can I keep the formatting of the previously occupied cells the same as the pivot table background color. Now when the table is contracted the empty cells are blank.
i.e. When the table contracts, I want the cells that used to have data in them to be filled with a certain color.

I'm sure I could use a VBA solution for this with the "Range.Area" method but I would prefer to not use VBA.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Conditional Format.

1st select the area to set background

[image: Area To Colour]

2nd, SetUp the Conditional Format, new rule.

[image: Conditional Format]

[image: New Rule]

then "Format Only Cells that Contains" (sorry my excel is in spanish lol), 
[image: Format Only Cells that Contains]

And Select "Blanks"

[image: Blanks]

Set the format you want:

[image: Format]

and Aceept!

now you have a nice format:

[image: Nice Format]

and if you change options in the pivotTable the format keep looking good. and no VBA is used

[image: Nice Format too]

hope help you, bye!

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the quick response!